# Hibernate query doesn't work with value as a bound parameter (?) but works when placed in query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

My question is: why the following query work?

```
String hql = "select sum(total) from Sale s where s.customerType = 'LOYAL' and s.customer.id = 4";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
System.out.println(query.getSingleResult()); // prints 1500.0 (exact value)
```

With the query above Hibernate executes the following SQL (which is fine):

```
select
        sum(sale0_.total) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        sales sale0_ 
    where
        sale0_.customer_type='LOYAL' 
        and sale0_.customer_id=4
```

**But when I try the first snippet with the following changes then it throws an exception.**

```
String hql = "select sum(total) from Sale s where s.customerType = 'LOYAL' and s.customer.id = ?";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter(1, 4);
System.out.println(query.getSingleResult()); // It doesn't work!
```

Exception: (it isn't the whole log, it is just a partial log but I think it will be enough)

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.markRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:717) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.model.Sale.lambda$getSumOfTotalNotCashFor$1(Sale.java:309) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.support.util.DBUtil.exec(DBUtil.java:53) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.model.Sale.getSumOfTotalNotCashFor(Sale.java:307) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.Shmeryal.test(Shmeryal.java:94) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.Shmeryal.start(Shmeryal.java:23) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.markRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:717) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.model.Sale.lambda$getSumOfTotalNotCashFor$1(Sale.java:309) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.support.util.DBUtil.exec(DBUtil.java:53) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.model.Sale.getSumOfTotalNotCashFor(Sale.java:307) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.Shmeryal.test(Shmeryal.java:94) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.karyal.shmeryal.Shmeryal.start(Shmeryal.java:23) ~[Shmeryal/:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Exception in Application start method
```

**Note:** I'm using Hibernate *`org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.4.9.Final`*

Comment: The positional parameters were removed after version **Hibernate 5.3.2** or later.
Your code will compile successfully but will fail in runtime.

Comment: So what will be the solution? @DiegoBascans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(total) from Sale s where s.customerType = 'LOYAL' and s.customer.id = :customer_id");
query.setParameter("customer_id", 4L);
System.out.println("Sum of total from sale is : " + query.list().get(0));
```

Comment: Thank you, it woks now; but need a tiny change replace `4` to `4L`

Comment: without that it will throw a ClassCast exception, because Hibernate want a long value for a model id so then it is trying to cast the int `4` to a long value.